# How to avoid merge conflict when both master and branch had been updated?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

### Branches:

Suppose $`git branch` returns:

```
-master

-branch1

-upstream/master

-upstream/branch2
```

### Node map:

[image]

### Situation:

1. `upstream/branch2(newest)` approved changes made in `local/branch1(newest)`.
2. `upstream/branch2(newest)` wants to incorporate *all* changes made in `local/branch1 (newest)`.
3. There are files that were modified by both branches, `upstream/branch2(newest)` and `local/branch1(neweset)`.
4. There are files that were *NOT* modified by neither of branches, `upstream/branch2(newest)` nor `local/branch1(neweset)`.
5. There are files that were modified by `local/branch1(neweset)`.
6. There are files that were modified only by `upstream/branch2(newest)`

### Question:

1. How do I merge `local/branch1(newest)`  to `upstream/branch2(newest)` with no merge conflicts?
2. If there must be merge conflicts, then, what is the best practice to minimize hard-coding (manual copy-and-paste with $`diff` all files) needed?

Could you please help me with the actual commands?

---

Assuming all commands were executed with `sudo` permission:

**#1**: Fetch the data from the upstream:

```
git fetch --all
```

**#2**: Switch to master branch:

```
git checkout master
```

**#3**: Create a branch2

```
git branch branch2
```

**#4**: Checkout branch2

```
git checkout branch2
```

**#5**: Pull data from upstream

```
git pull upstream branch2
```

**#6**: Merge branch1

```
git merge branch1
```

The above is what I can think of, but I think there will be merge conflict at step #6.... Is there a better way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Conflicts happen, they're normal and unavoidable. It doesn't matter that files were change in both branches, what matters is whether both branches have incompatible change to the *same* file. When this happens there's nothing to do but resolve the resulting conflict.

Comment: There is no technical solution to avoiding merge conflicts, only communication between people working on the different branches so that you avoid editing the same areas of the same files on the branches to be merge. However, I am interested to know why you want to avoid merge conflicts so strongly.

Comment: @CharlesBailey I don't know how to resolve the merge conflicts, rather than locating each markers within the text and manually erase them... I do not have mergetools available to me now, and I have a lot of changes in `local/branch1`, so resolving the merge conflicts may take a lot of time..

Comment: @meagar Should I pull files that were changed by either `upstream/branch2` or `local/branch1` to `local/master` first?

Comment: Then what? What would that accomplish? Eventually you're going to either throw out somebody's work, or resolve a conflict. If two people edit the same parts of the same file, you *must* resolve that conflict. There's no magic way around this.

Comment: You can take a look at some popular 3-way merge tools to help you visualize the conflicts and help you in merging them. One popular such tool I can think of and have personally used is `p4merge`. You need to set up the difftool with `git config --global merge.tool p4merge` and `git config --global mergetool.p4merge.cmd 'p4merge \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\"'`. The tool would automatically merge the easy merges for you and can guide you through resolving the conflicts.

Comment: Agree with previous posters, conflicts happen. After you resolve, simply use `git add <path-to-filename>` and commit back upstream.